Dynamical system determine stability
Let the non-trivial polynomial $ Q(x, y) $, with $ Q(0, 0) = 0 $, and the autonomous dynamical system:
\begin{equation}
x' = y - x^3 \cos(Q(x, y))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y' = -x - y^3 \cos(Q(x, y))
\end{equation}
I found that the equilibrium point is $(0,0)$ and for stability i have tried using the Hartman-Grobman theorem, but I get eigenvalues with zero real part. Then, I attempted with a Lyapunov function and i used $L(x,y)=ax^{2}+by^{2}$, but it failed. Now I am stuck.

@Moo I think it works too. One just needs to restrict to a neighborhood of the origin so $\cos(Q(x,y)) > 0$.

In a neighborhood of (0,0), the cos is positive; did you use this?

thank you!!!!!!
